# forms authentication fails for POST request, .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

In my .Net MVC application, I have default controller, which anyone should have access (as it contains the welcome page, register, login, password reset methods etc). All the other controllers have been inherited from a controller with authorize attribute.

I can browse to default/index, and default/register pages(i.e. any request of GET type). But any POST request to a default controller action acts like they need authorization. For example, when the user enters email/password and click login, it makes a POST request to default/login.

I tried with setting location paths in webconfig but still no luck. I have noticed that every POST request returns the form authorization cookie with empty in its value, while GET requests do not send back auth cookie.
Any idea what I have missed?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Anuruddha

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //...
}
```